rviz2 crash with error Could not find a root element for package manifest at ...\package.xml
I am using ros2 Jazzy on Windows 10
when trying to start rviz2 it generates this error
[INFO] [1725644109.800974900] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[INFO] [1725644109.801507700] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[INFO] [1725644109.903766400] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ERROR] [1725644109.910675500] [pluginlib.ClassLoader]: Could not find a root element for package manifest at c:\opt\ros2/share/rviz_default_plugins\package.xml.
[ERROR] [1725644109.911132200] [pluginlib.ClassLoader]: Could not find package manifest (neither package.xml or deprecated manifest.xml) at same directory level as the plugin XML file c:\opt\ros2/share/rviz_default_plugins/plugins_description.xml. Plugins will likely not be exported properly.
)

and when I followed up the error I found this exception
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9F6E9286E (ucrtbase.dll) in rviz2.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

and when I run ros2 doctor I get some warning about updating rviz2
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\network.py: 154: UserWarning: Interface flags are not available on Windows. Run `ipconfig` to see what interfaces are available.
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: gz_math_vendor has been updated to a new version. local: 0.0.5 < latest: 0.0.6
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: message_filters has been updated to a new version. local: 4.11.1 < latest: 4.11.2
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rmw_cyclonedds_cpp has been updated to a new version. local: 2.2.1 < latest: 2.2.2
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_adapter has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_cli has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_cmake has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_generator_c has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_generator_cpp has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_generator_type_description has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_parser has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_pycommon has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_runtime_c has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_runtime_cpp has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_typesupport_interface has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp has been updated to a new version. local: 4.6.3 < latest: 4.6.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rqt_bag has been updated to a new version. local: 1.5.3 < latest: 1.5.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rqt_bag_plugins has been updated to a new version. local: 1.5.3 < latest: 1.5.4
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz2 has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_assimp_vendor has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_common has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_default_plugins has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_ogre_vendor has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_rendering has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_rendering_tests has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
c:\opt\ros2\Lib\site-packages\ros2doctor\api\package.py: 122: UserWarning: rviz_visual_testing_framework has been updated to a new version. local: 14.1.2 < latest: 14.1.5
--report` to see full list.

All 5 checks passed

How to overcome this problem
